# Force a maximized window on user's machine?

Tags: javascript, angular, css, window, multiple-monitors

Tech using: JS, jQuery, CSS3, HTML5, and Anguler(4+).

User's system is usually a Windows machine running 2 monitors.

Is there a way to programmatically force maximized window on the user's machine and one further force it across multiple monitors?

The only thing that is coming to my mind is somehow grabs the user's monitor size or monitors size.

The users (a certain set of people) for this Web App - want it to take up the entire screen views.

Comment: Even if you could, why would you want to? That's a quick way to have users never return to your website.

Comment: @JoelCDoyle Added this to the main thread - The users (a certain set of people) for this Web App - want it to take up the entire screen views.

Comment: Do you want a multi-screen webapp, beyond the maximized first window? You may want to look at [Presentation API](https://www.w3.org/TR/presentation-api/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's user's responsibility to resize browser window to the appropriate size. A regular window (not a pop-up that was opened with `window.open`, as another answer explains) cannot be controlled by a website because a website doesn't own this window - there may be other tabs in this window that are equal in rights.

> The users (a certain set of people) for this Web App - want it to take up the entire screen views.

A desktop application (Electron or NW.js) may be considered to provide required UX for for this set of people. In its most simple form it can be just a wrapper for a website with necessary usability improvements.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot resize a  main windows, only for dynamic created windows

Only if you created it with **window.open**

:You can't resize a window or tab that wasn’t created by window.open.

You can't resize a window or tab when it’s in a window with more than one tab.

If you have used **window.open** , you can always try this :

```
window.moveTo(0, 0);

window.resizeTo(screen.availWidth, screen.availHeight);
```

it might works depends on browser but as a personal experience , forcing user to resize is not always good